# tweepy favorite_count repeats the original tweet likes

Tags: python, tweepy

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I try to retrieve a tweets from a hashtag most of the tweets are retweets of an origin tweet and they all repeat the same like and retweet number. For example if I have a tweet with over 100 likes and 20 retweets and there are over 10 retweets of my tweet all 10 of those tweets will have 100 likes and 20 retweets, which is redundant data. This is a very big issue especially because I usually retrieve about 5000 - 10000 tweets for analysis.

Code:

```
from os import access
import tweepy 
import configparser    
import pandas as pd

api_key = ''
api_key_secret = ''

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# user = '@elonmusk'
keywords = '#AsiaCup2022'
limit = 10000

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q = keywords, count = 100, tweet_mode =     'extended').items(limit)

# tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = user, count = limit, tweet_mode = 'extended')

columns = ['User', 'Tweet', 'Likes', 'Retweets']
data = []

for tweet in tweets:
    try:
        data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text,         tweet.retweeted_status.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count])
    except: 
        data.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text, tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_excel("Cup2022.xlsx")
```

An example of what my issue is:
[image: Issue]

As you can see in the pic the same tweet has been retweeted by two different users and they have the same like and retweet count as the original tweet. Any help would be appreciated, this is a really big problem for me considering it messes up my entire result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the retweets from the results of your search.

```py
keywords = '#AsiaCup2022 -filter:retweets'
```

That way you will get only the original tweets and you will avoid that redundancy.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you provide the link of the docs from where you got the -filter parameter.

Comment: @FakhrAli Sure: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators